# Retrieve Redshift error messages

Tags: amazon-redshift, datagrip

I'm running queries on a Redshift cluster using DataGrip that take upwards of 10 hours to run and unfortunately these often fail. Alas, DataGrip doesn't maintain a connection to the database long enough for me to get to see the error message with which the queries fail.

Is there a way of retrieving these error messages later, e.g. using internal Redshift tables? Alternatively, is there are a way to make DataGrip maintain the connection for long enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you Can! 
Query `stl_connection_log` table to find out `pid` by looking at the `recordtime` column when your connection was initiated and also `dbname`, `username` and `duration` column helps to narrow down.

> select * from stl_connection_log order by recordtime desc limit 100

If you can find the `pid`, you can query `stl_query` table to find out if are looking at right query.

> select * from stl_query where pid='XXXX' limit 100

Then, check the `stl_error` table for your `pid`. This will tell you the error you are looking for.

> select * from stl_error where pid='XXXX' limit 100

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.