# See why an Amazon Redshift scheduled query fails

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a scheduled query in Redshift that simply will not run. It works when I execute the query manually in the query editor, just not when scheduled. I can't seem to find any feedback about *why* it's failing, though. I can see the schedule history, a unique Id, and the status of "Failed", but no more info.

Is there a system table/view that I can dig into and find out what's going on with my query? The SQL consists of basic `select`, `update`, `insert` style code - nothing fancy, just long.

Comment: Any updates on this? I see you posted this 4 months ago... maybe you figured it out since then, because I have the EXACT same question...

Comment: Nope. I eventually deleted it, and made it into a couple of smaller queries. No changes, just smaller and it worked. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for any errors using:

```
select 
    process, 
    errcode, 
    linenum as line,
    trim(error) as err
from 
    stl_error;
```

Also: [Retrieve Redshift error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245557/retrieve-redshift-error-messages)

Ref.: [STL_ERROR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_ERROR.html)

Comment: this table is not accessible on redshift serverless, any alternatives?  i dont see it in sys_query_history

Answer (score 0):

It says in the description that it doesn't record SQL errors which would likely be the problem of the failed query.

I'm trying to sort this one as well and it seems it's limited as I only see the

[image: Error]

Any idea how to get the associated query ID, PID, or EID so I can check maybe against the query history?